# how do I find integrals where one limit tends to infinity?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

As in this question, where putting in the value of infinity makes it unsolvable.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} (x+1)} \, dx$$

so I wrote this integral as an integral with limits 0 to t where t tends to infinity after that I substituted, put x= k^2 and thus the integral became (integral from 0 to infinity of)2/(1+k^2) which came out to be arctan(k) where limits are 0 to infinity. So then it should be arctanx - arctan0 where x tends to infinity?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx$

Comment: That type of integral is called an improper integral.

Comment: There is no trouble at infinity. If you are in a mood to be very careful, you may want to find the integral from $\epsilon$ to $b$, and let $\epsilon\to0^+$ and $b\to\infty$.

Comment: @Suhail I tried doing that but I still can't solve it. I will mention what steps I took in the question above.

Comment: $\arctan x$ has limit $\pi/2$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Maybe the question got changed in an edit. My interpretation of the original non-TeX was $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}$. It would be good if OP clarified the intent.

Comment: No I meant the previous one. The edited version puts a root on the complete denominator whereas I put it only on 'x'. The editing was done automatically (not by me).

Answer (score 1):

Yes: the limit of $\arctan{a}$ as $a \to \infty$ is $\pi/2$.

There are lots of ways to evaluate the integral, but we can immediately see that it is convergent because $x^{-1/2}$ is an integrable singularity at $x=0$ and the integrand behaves as $x^{-3/2}$ as $x \to \infty$.

The value of the integral is $\pi$ because

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)} = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+u^2} = 2 \lim_{a \to \infty} \left [\arctan{a}-\arctan{0} \right ] = 2 \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$$

There are other ways to show this, i.e., residue theorem.